# log file missing messages

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, debian-jessie

I have a log file I track on my own. I am running a python script on raspberry pi and printing messages at various parts/events of the code. I have the script outputs piped to a text file. Some cycles all messages are logged and other cycles hardly anything is logged. The exact same events happen each cycle so I should see the same messages logged. What would cause this to happen? Is this a python issue or linux issue? **The script does not crash but the logging is inconsistent.**

example command running in my /etc/rc.local folder:

```
sudo python test.py >> log.txt&
```

Comment: Would be useful if you can clarify how you are setting up the `loghandler` with some sample code. Flushing your log messages `sys.stdout.flush()` may help if you are writing `std out`. Also note that you are not redirecting the error steam. `sudo python test.py >> log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @MaxArbiter I am not using loghandler. It's simply just status updates I was pushing to my text file.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`sudo python test.py >>log.txt 2>&1`

Here:

- `>>log.txt`: opens the file in **append mode** and **redirect `stdout` there**.
- `2>&1`: **redirects `stderr` to where stdout is currently going**. In this case, it is your log file opened in append mode. &1 reuses the file descriptor which standout is currently using.